# How to convert birthday to age using datetime, but on an entire pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, series

I have the following code:

```
def birthdayToAge(birthday, reference):
    return reference.year - birthday.year - ((reference.month, reference.day) < (birthday.month, birthday.day))
```

This works on individual values, but generates the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` when applied to two series. The cause of this error is the "<".

How do I change the ("<" in the) function to not get this error?

Comment: Close.  Think of it the *other* way around. Send the function into your DataFrame, rather than the DataFrame into the function.  Do a bit of research on the `df.apply` function.  This enables a function to be executed on each row of your DataFrame, with the output able to be stored into a new column.

Comment: @S3DEV you have the `.dt` accessor, why would you need and apply here?

Comment: .dt does not work. It produces the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: broadcast reference to a series ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are converting series to datetime.
df['birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthday'])

## Define a function to calculate age

```
df['birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthday'])
def calculate_age(birthday):
    today = datetime.now()
    age = today.year - birthday.year - ((today.month, today.day) <(birthday.month, birthday.day))
    return age
```

Comment: pd.to_datetime() has no effect. My dtypes are already datetime64[ns]

Comment: What can i see is that your code seems to be fine. The issue could have been in the conversion of (birthday, reference) to DateTime. As u mentioned your datatype for birthday is correct so once verify datatype of reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, using the numpy timedelta to get the distance in years from the reference instead of calculating it yourself.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random
import numpy as np

def birthdayToAge(birthday,reference):
    return np.floor((reference-birthday)/np.timedelta64(1,"Y"))

data = {"birthday":[datetime.datetime.now()- datetime.timedelta(days=random.randint(800,800*10)) for x in range(10)],
        "randomdata":[random.randint(1,5) for x in range(10)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["age"] = birthdayToAge(df["birthday"],datetime.datetime.now())

print(df)
```